# Map is not defined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I am getting an error that says:

> "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

I am not sure what can be wrong. Can someone help me fix it please?
This is the code where I used map:

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from './Product'
export default function Main(props){
    const{products}=props;
    return(
      <main className="block col-2">
          <h2> Products</h2>
              <div className="row">
     {products.map((product)=>(
    <Product key={product.id} product={product}/>
))}
              </div>
         
          </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you add the code where you are rendering `<Main products=.. />` ?

Comment: Simply `products` is undefined. The place you are using the `Main` component supposed to send products prop. Once you send array as the prop that error will go away.

Comment: Search for the error on your favorite search engine and you'll find many examples of why it occurs. Most likely, at the time `Main` runs, the `products` prop has not been defined, because of an asynchronous call or something like that. Without that information in the question, however, all we can do is guess, as the answers you've received do.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you’re not passing products into the props. That could be because you’re waiting for a state update, in which case doing `products?.map(...)` would solve your issue. Otherwise, you can set a default value by doing `const {products = []} = props`.

Answer (score -1):

When the component firsts renders it is likely the `products` variable is undefined.

Use the && operator like this `{products && products.map(product => ...)}`. This way it checks to see if products is a thing before trying to perform a map on a non existent array. Once the props update, the component will re-render with products and show in the component.

So full code would be:

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from './Product'
export default function Main(props){
    const{products}=props;
    return(
      <main className="block col-2">
          <h2> Products</h2>
              <div className="row">
     {products && products.map((product)=>(
    <Product key={product.id} product={product}/>
))}
              </div>
         
          </main>
    )
}
```